# Why Highcharts not render ploted images when exporting locally offline chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

I'm trying to export a chart locally, on the client side, using latest version of Highcharts and it's dependencies.

The export occours normaly, the chart is exported in a PNG image. But when the exporting is done by offline exporting, the png image 'sun.png' isn't exported, i just see a blank square.

In the other hand, when i remove 'offline-exporting.js' and the line 'fallbackToExportServer: false' to exporting using Highcharts's servers, the 'sun.png' is exported normaly. I've tried use a bmp image, base64 image, local image, and the result is always the same.

```
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">/script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/lib/svg2pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/lib/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/lib/canvg.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<button id="export">Export chart locally</button>
```

and the javascript code to export:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    allowHTML: true,
    fallbackToExportServer: false
  },

  series: [{
    data: [71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 54.4],
    
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,
      allowOverlap: true,
      format: '<img src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png"></img>'
    
    }
  }]
});

$('#export').click(function() {
  chart.exportChartLocal({ type: 'image/png' });
});
```

When i try offline-exporting, on the client side, the result is:
[image: offline Highcharts exporting]

When the exports is 'online', the result is:
[image]

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2tubpfnc/

Thank in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The only way that I found to solve this question is convert the png image to a base64 image, set a class to 'img'  element, and then set that base64 image to each 'img' element using callback function of Highcharts.chart.

```
let image = new Image();
        image.src = "data:image/png;base64, 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";
```

For the dataLabels:

```
format: '<img id="sun" width="25px" height="25px"></img>'
```

and to the callback function of Highcharts.chart

```
()=>{$('[id=sun]').attr('src', image.src)}
```

A live demo is here if someone need: http://jsfiddle.net/b7zejnqy/